# function type for C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers

What's the different between:
int(&)(int,int)
and
int(*)(int,int)

The full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>
template<typename T>
std::string type_name()
{
  std::string r;
  using TR=typename std::remove_reference<T>::type;
  std::unique_ptr<char, void(*)(void*)> own(abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(TR).name(), nullptr, nullptr, nullptr), std::free);
  r = own.get();
  if(std::is_const<TR>::value)
  {
    r += "[const] ";
  }
  if(std::is_volatile<TR>::value)
  {
    r += "[volatile] ";
  }
  if(std::is_lvalue_reference<T>::value)
  {
    r += "[&] ";
  }
  else if(std::is_rvalue_reference<T>::value)
  {
    r += "[&&] ";
  }
  return r;
}
int add(int i, int j)
{
  return i+j;
}
auto func()->int(&)(int,int)
{
  return add;
}
auto func2()->int(*)(int,int)
{
  return add;
}
int main()
{
  std::cout<<func()(1,2)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<func2()(1,2)<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<type_name<decltype(func())>()<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<type_name<decltype(func2())>()<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The output for func()(1,2) and func2(1,2) are both 3.
What's the different between:
int(&)(int,int)
and
int(*)(int,int)
and type_name prints:
int (int, int)[&]
int (*)(int, int)
the second one is a function pointer, what about the first one?

Comment: Another question is, why the following declaration is not OK:
auto func3()->decltype(add)
{
  return add;
}
but this declaration is OK:
auto func3()->decltype(add) &
{
  return add;
}

Comment: The following declaration is valid in C++:
decltype(add) x;
what is x? and how to initialize it or assign a value to it?

In C++, what's the difference about "return add" and "return &add"?